# How to use fa-plus-circle icon next to a text field using CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, textfield

I want to use fa-plus-circle item next to the text field as below. How can I achieve that using CSS and HTMl. I haven't use any CSS right now since it's affecting to all the other places that using fa-plus-circle.

[image]

**.html**

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" >My Name <span class="fa fa-star required-field"></span> </label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control"><span
             class="fa fa-plus-circle text-success cursor-point"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: using any bootstrap version ?

Comment: Hi @LaljiTadhani.  **"ngx-bootstrap": "^7.1.0"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/input-group/

You can use input group for this

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-text">
    <span class="fa fa-plus-circle text-success cursor-point"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But I have to do bootstrap css overwrite here, **Border:0px** and **background-color: white**. Is it ok to do bootstrap css Overwrite?

Comment: Yes. It is okay to overwrite bootstrap css to match your design

Answer (score 1):

Try This way

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="flex-fill">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <span class="ml-3 fa fa-plus-circle text-success cursor-point"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this works. But **ml-3** is not working inside my application. Why is that?